# Python with Postgres

Tags: python, postgresql, formatting

```
unload ('SELECT *
FROM "knet-data"."knet-user" where amzn_alias not like '%DELETED%' ')
                   to 's3://pets-data-pipelines/knet-user/2021-12-13/knet-user_20211214160851.csv_'
                   iam_role 'arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxxxx:role/upload_data_to_S3'
                   DELIMITER as '\t' ADDQUOTES ALLOWOVERWRITE
                   manifest;

def exec_sel_qry(db_engine,db_conn,qry):
    if db_engine == 'mysql':
        qry_result = []
        try:
            cur = db_conn.cursor()
            cur.execute(qry)
            qry_result = cur.fetchall()
            cur.close()
        except mysql.connector.Error as e:
            logger.info(str(e))
            raise e
    elif db_engine == 'redshift':
        qry_result = []
        try:
            query = db_conn.query(qry)
            qry_result = query.getresult()
        except pg.ProgrammingError as e:
            comment(e.message)
    return qry_result

search = 'DELETED'
#like_val = f'%{search}%'
sel_stmt = '''unload ('SELECT %s
            FROM \"%s\".\"%s\" where e_alias not like '%%%s%%' ')
               to '%s_'
               iam_role 'arn:aws:iam::4xxxxxxxxx:role/upload_data_to_S3'
               DELIMITER as '\\t' ADDQUOTES ALLOWOVERWRITE
               manifest;'''%(column_list,from_schema,table_name,search,file_name)
print(sel_stmt)
```

My goal is to unload the data with the condition specified in where clause, however the query throws an error.

How do I get past this error? I have some issue with formatting.
Ideally I would like to unload

Select * from schema_name.table_name where column not like '%deleted%'

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "knet_user.py", line 56, in exec_qry
db_conn.query(qry)
pg.ProgrammingError: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "%"
LINE 2: ...knet-data"."knet-user" where e_alias not like '%DELETED%'...
```

Comment: Not sure what driver you are using to connect to Postgres, but I'm betting it needs `'%%DELETED%%'` as `%` is generally the placeholder marker.

Comment: The error itself is because of the quoting though I think. You are quoting the entire string with single quotes and then try and embed single quotes in the string too. Escape the single-quotes.

Comment: search = 'DELETED'
    #like_val = f'%{search}%'
    sel_stmt = '''unload ('SELECT %s
                FROM \"%s\".\"%s\" where amzn_alias not like '%%%s%%' ')
                   to '%s_'
                   iam_role 'arn:aws:iam::446567294750:role/upload_data_to_S3'
                   DELIMITER as '\\t' ADDQUOTES ALLOWOVERWRITE
                   manifest;'''%(column_list,from_schema,table_name,search,file_name)
    print(sel_stmt)

Comment: There seems to be an extra % before "DELETED" - 3 instead of 2.